# WPF - MVVM Light - Unity - Events don't fire when reloading current usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, service-locator

I have an interesting problem with events not firing when a view is replaced with itself.

First, the setup:  I'm creating the connection between the ViewModel and the View inside the App.xaml resource dictionary:

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
     <v:MyView />
 </DataTemplate>
```

I have an application stage where I create my instance using ServiceLocator:

```
this.stageViewModel.ActiveStageViewModel = Util.GetInstanceFromDI<MyViewModel>();
```

And inside my stage, I use a content control bound to the ActiveStageViewModel to pull it all together:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ActiveStageViewModel}" Margin="0" />
```

All this works great, and when I navigate to MyViewModel, the correct view shows up and looks fine. All of the load and resize events fire normally.

HOWEVER, if I try to navigate to the MyViewModel a second time, none of the events fire, except DataContextChanged.

I use an Observer to monitor size changed events so that I can decide on some styling and scrolling options, so I need for the load events to fire on the second load in order to refresh the values in my observer.  In any case, not firing the events on a duplicate view load seems like a performance feature that is interfering rather than helping.

What it APPEARS to be doing is making a comparison between what is rendered and what will be rendered, and simply not firing the events if the rendering isn't changed.

I have tried a few things to force the updates, with little success, or a success which kind of breaks the MVVM approach I'm going for.

The first thing I tried was nulling out the ActiveStageViewModel before resetting the instance.  That doesn't work at all.  My guess is that because it never renders anything, it never drops the cached View.

The second thing I tried was forcing an FrameworkElement.InvalidateMeasure(), FrameworkElement.InvalidateArrange() and FrameworkElement.InvalidateVisual() when the DataContextChanged event fires.  This doesn't work by itself, presumably because the Cached View comparison still happens.

Finally, what worked (but sucks), is attaching a DataContextChanged event to the View, and then setting the height on the element inside the event handler.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MyViewModel}">
    <v:MyView DataContextChanged="FrameworkElement_DataContextChanged" />
</DataTemplate>




private void FrameworkElement_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10) };
    var el = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    bool addOperation = false;
    double height = el.ActualHeight;
    timer.Tick += (s,ev) =>
    {
        el.Height = addOperation ? height + .001 : height - .001;
        addOperation = !addOperation;
        if (!addOperation)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    };

    timer.Start();
}
```

This works because I'm effectively forcing a layout change inside the DataContextChanged event (twice, in 20 milliseconds, so it's not observable to the user), which *apparently* invalidates whatever view cache comparison that's going on.  Obviously, adding an eventhandler inside the View/View Model declaration doesn't conform to MVVM's loose coupling scheme.  Sure, it's at the application setup, but still seems awful.

Does anyone have any experience with this phenomenon, and a way to force re-rendering without such a brute force hack?

Comment: Loaded is raised when the control is loaded; changing the DataContext is different. I would imagine it's not resizing when you replace the DataContext. DataContextChanged is the event you care about. However, in WPF, the "correct" way to do the sort of stuff you're doing here is declaratively in XAML with styles and triggers and so on, rather than in code behind. WPF is extraordinarily recalcitrant when you don't do things the way it wants you to. It's like giving a pill to a feral cat sometimes.

Comment: That's normal behaviour, since, in your ServiceLocator, you're holding one Instance of your UserControl, which is loaded just once, if you want to show that control second time, there is no need for load it again, so event with OnLoaded won't fire.

Comment: Just tell us what exactly you want to do, I'm sure you can do this without code-behind hacks to fire your code-behind events

Comment: The issue is that when it's reloaded, it's dumped the Observer.  I rely on the observer to initialize values (like actual height, which is not available for binding directly to the viewmodel) in the viewmodel, which in turn turns on visibility for things like pager controls (which display as fully opaque, and transparent depending on the scroll position and height).  The observer triggers on a size changed or load event, but those don't fire when you're re-rendering the same control.

Comment: Actually, I just figured it out.  I can just add DataContext to the observer and key off the DataContextChanged event in addition to sizechanged.  This centralizes the event code back in the observer where it's meant to be.  -- Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: @sTrenat - out of curiosity,  is there a way to override that behavior and force the re-render every time?

Comment: @nixkuroi Try this: this.stageViewModel.ActiveStageViewModel = Util.GetInstanceFromDI<MyViewModel>(System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString())  

I'm not sure how is your ServiceLocator looks

Comment: But remember to unregister your ViewModel on closing, I think that there is some way in your Framework, i don't know Mvvm light well.

Comment: @sTrenat Didn't work, but I suspect it's because I have to register that key ahead of time in order to get it back.  I appreciate the suggestion, and I'll keep it in my back pocket if I refactor my navigation scheme.